# Unbiased estimator having a deviation less than $0.05$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, parameter-estimation

In a mass production of items produced indepedently of eachother the probability of an item being defect is $p$. An unbiased estimator for $p$ is

$\hat p = \frac{X}{n}$ where $X$ = amount of items with a defect and $n$ is amount of produced items.

Assume $p = 0.12$ and $n = 55$. Use that $\hat p$ under these conditions is approximately normally distributed to calculate the probability that the unbiased estimator $\hat p$ deviates less than $0.05$ from the true $p$.

So I want to find $P(|\hat p -p| < 0.05)$. If i want to use the standard normal distribution I have to know $z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$.

Given $p=0.12$, I find $E(X) = 6.6$. And since we want $\hat p$ to deviate less than $0.05$, I set $\sigma = 0.05$.

if $X$ deviates less than $0.05$ the maximum amount of defects can be $6.05$ and the minimum $5.95$. Using this to find what values $Z$ has to be between gives me big numbers, which can't be true... What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\hat{p}$ as an estimate makes us $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confident that the error will not exceed $$z_{\alpha / 2} \sqrt{\hat{p} \hat{q} / n}$$

If we want the error to be $.05$, then we have $$.05 = z_{\alpha / 2} \sqrt{(.12)(.88)/ 55}$$

When I solved  I got $z_{\alpha /2} = 1.141$, which implies that $\alpha \approx 0.254$

So the probability that the estimate $\hat{p}$ doesn't deviate from the actual value of $p$ by more than $.05$ is $100(1-\alpha)\% = 74.6\%$

Comment: What does the variable $z_{\alpha/2}$ mean?

Comment: It's the corresponding z-value on the standard normal distribution where $\alpha /2$ of the area is to the right of $z$ and \alpha /2$ of the area is to the left of -$z$. Think of this entire process like creating a confidence interval, but instead we are going backwards. We are given the interval (between .05) and we need to find the level of significance for this interval. If you were to find a $74.6$ percent confidence interval here, you would get the interval to be roughly $(\hat{p} -.05, \hat{p} + .05)$

Comment: Can you fix the latex =)

Comment: I forgot a dollar sign, whoops. Wish the mobile app showed latex in comments... but anyway:It's the corresponding z-value on the standard normal distribution, where $\alpha /2$ is to right of $z$ and $\alpha /2$ is to left of $-z$. Think of this process as finding a confidence interval, but in reverse. You're given the interval (.05) and we want the level of significance. If you were to find a $74.6$ percent confidence interval, you would get the interval to be roughly $(\hat{p} -.05, \hat{p} + .05)$

Comment: Ok, so I haven't learned about confidence intervals yet... How did you find $\alpha = 0.254$ once you know $z_{\alpha/2} = 1.141$?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a calculator. If you have a TI-84 you can use the already-built-in-function$$ \text{normalcdf}(1.141, 1E99, 0, 1)$$ This will find the area under the curve from 1.141 to infinity with a normal distribution with mean 0 and s.d 1 (the standard normal) and remember that this will only give you half of $.254$, we need to also include the area from negative infinity to -1.141 so you need to multiply by $2$

Comment: If I do not have such a calculator, is there an alternative approach where I can use tables? I am only allowed to use tables in statistics to solve such problems. What happens if $n=75$ istead?